# Using Heaps and a Process Control Block to create a Scheduling Simulator

Tags: c++, heap, scheduling, simulator

So I am trying to create a scheduling simulator based on a priority value. I have a process control block header shown below that has all the necessary values to use for scheduling. My question is that when I store my PCB into the heap in my main loop, I do not know how to organize the heap by the priority value, -20 being the first in priority and 19 being last. It seems like when I store the PCB in the heap it will not be organized by any of the values and just have a random output when I choose to remove or peek a value. Any help would be appreciated! (If you need me to explain further just comment so!)

Heap.h:

```
    #include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

#ifndef HEAP_H
#define HEAP_H

using namespace std;

/**
 * This class reports Heap exceptions.
 */
class HeapException
{
private:
   /**
    * Reason for the exception
    */
   string message;  
public:
   /**
    * Constructs a HeapException
    * @param aMessage why the exception occurred
    */
   HeapException(const string& aMessage)
   {
      message = aMessage;
   }   
   /**
    * Gives a reason for this exception
    * @return why the this exception occurred
    */
   string what() const
   {
      return message;
   }
};

template <typename E>
class Heap
{
private:
   /**
    * A complete tree stored in a vector representing this 
    * binary heap
    */
   vector<E> tree;
   /**
    * Swaps a parent and child elements of this heap at the specified     indices
    * @param place an index of the child element on this heap
    * @param parent an index of the parent element on this heap
    */   
   void swap(int place, int parent);
   /**
    * Rebuilds the heap to ensure that the heap property of the tree is preserved.
    * @param root the root index of the subtree to be rebuilt
    * @param eSize the size of this tree
    */   
   void reheapify(int root, int eSize);   
public:
   /**
      Constructs an empty heap;
   */
   Heap<E>();

   /**
      destructor - returns the heap memory to the system;
   */
   ~Heap<E>();

   /**
      Determine whether the heap is empty.
      @return true if the heap is empty;
      otherwise, it returns false if the tree contains at least one item.
   */
   bool isEmpty() const;

   /**
      Inserts an item into the heap.
      @param item the value to be inserted.
      @return none
   */
   void insert(E item);

   /**
      An exception is generated if this method is invoked
      by an empty heap. The maximum/minimum value is removed
      from the heap if the heap is not empty and its effective
      size is reduced by 1.
      @return the maximum (in the case of a maxheap) or the
      minimum (in the case of a minheap) on the heap.
   */
   E remove() throw (HeapException);

   /**
      An exception is generated if this method is invoked
      by an empty heap
      @return the maximum (in the case of a maxheap) or the
      minimum (in the case of a minheap) on the heap.
   */
   const E& peek() const throw (HeapException);


   /**
      @return the size of the heap; the effective size of the 
      heap.
   */
   int size() const;
};
//HEAP_H
#endif
```

Heap.cpp:

```
#include "Heap.h"

using namespace std;

template <typename E>
Heap<E>::Heap()
{
   // compiler-generated code .. no need to implement this
}

template <typename E>
Heap<E>::~Heap()
{
   while(tree.size() > 0)
      tree.pop_back();
}

template <typename E>
bool Heap<E>::isEmpty() const
{
    if (tree.empty())
        return true;
    else return false;
}

template<typename E>
void Heap<E>::insert(E item)
{
    tree.push_back(item);
    int place = tree.size() - 1;
    int parent = place / 2;
    if (place % 2 == 0)
        parent = parent - 1;
    while (parent >= 0 && tree[place] > tree[parent]){
        swap(place,parent);
        place = parent;
        if (place % 2 == 0)
            int parent = (place / 2) - 1;
        else 
            parent = place / 2;
    }
}

template<typename E>
E Heap<E>::remove() throw (HeapException)
{
    if (isEmpty() == false){ 
    int child = tree.size() - 1;
    swap(child, 0);
    E number = tree.back();
    reheapify(0, tree.size());
    return number;}
    else {
        throw ("Attempted to remove from empty Heap");
    }



}

template<typename E>
const E& Heap<E>::peek() const throw (HeapException)
{
    if (isEmpty() == false)
        return tree[0];
    else throw ("Attempted to peek empty Heap");
}

template<typename E>
int Heap<E>::size()const
{
    return tree.size;
}


template<typename E>
void Heap<E>::swap(int place, int parent)
{
    E temp;
    temp = tree[place];
    tree[place] = tree[parent];
    tree[parent] = temp;

}

template<typename E>
void Heap<E>::reheapify(int root, int eSize)
{
    int child = 2 * root + 1;
    int right = 2 * root + 2;
    if (child < eSize){
        if (right < eSize && tree[right] < tree[child]){
                    child = child + 1;
         }
        if (tree[root] < tree[child]){
            swap(root, child);
            reheapify(child, eSize);
        }
    }
}
```

PCB.h:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class PCB
{
private:
   /**
    * the process ID
    */
   int pid;
   /**
    * the priority value of this process [-20,19]
    */
   int priority;
   /**
    * the running status of this process
    * [0 = not running, 1 = running]
    */
   int running;
   /**
    * the cycle during which this process was created
    */
   int arrived;
   /**
    * the quantum (number of cycles required to execute)
    * this process
    */
   int length;
   /**
    * the cycle when this process began running
    */
   int start;
   /**
    * the number of cycles from the creation of this process
    * to when it began running
    */
   int wait;    
public:
   /**
    * Create a a PCB with the lowest priority
    * and a quantum of 0 (default constructor)
    */
   PCB()
   {
      priority = 19;
      running = 0;
      arrived = 0;
      length = 0;
   }

   /**
    * Creates a PCB with the specified parameters.
    * @param id the process ID
    * @param pVal priority value [-20,19]
    * @param run executing status [0 = not running, 1 = running] 
    * @param arr the cycle during which the process arrived
    * @param len the quantum - number of cycles required to execute
    * the process
    */  
   PCB(int id, int pVal, int run, int arr, int len)
   {
      pid = id;
      priority = pVal;
      running = run;
      arrived = arr;
      length = len;
   }

   /**
    * Gives the ID for this process.
    * @return the pid of this process
    */    
   int getPid() const
   {
      return pid;
   }

   /**
    * Gives the priority value for this process.
    * @return the priority of this process
    */     
   int getPriority() const
   {
      return priority;
   }

   /**
    * Gives the running status of this process.
    * @return the running status of this process
    */    
   bool isExecuting() const
   {
      return (running == 1);
   }

   /**
    * Sets the running status of this process to 1.
    */     
   void execute()
   {
      running = 1;
   }

   /**
    * Gives the arrival time for this process.
    * @return cycle during with this process was created
    */     
   int getArrival() const
   {
      return arrived;
   }

   /**
    * Gives the quantum of this process.
    * @return the number of cycles required to execute this process
    */     
   int getLength() const
   {
      return length;
   }

   /**
    * Gives the cycle during which this process began running.
    * @return the cycle during which this process began running
    */     
   int getStart() const
   {
      return start;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the start cyle for this process.
    * @param startCycle the cycle during which this process began
    * running.
    */     
   void setStart(int startCycle)
   {
      start = startCycle;
   }

   /**
    * Gives the wait time for this process.
    * @return the number of cycles this process waited
    * before running.
    */     
   int getWait() const
   {
      return wait;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the wait time for this process.
    */     
   void setWait(int waitTime)
   {
      wait = waitTime;
   }

   /**
    * Overloaded == operator that determines whether
    * two process control blocks are the same.
    * @param pcb1 a process control block
    * @param pcb2 a process control block
    * @return true if the PCBs are the same; otherwise, false
    */
   friend bool operator==(const PCB& pcb1, const PCB& pcb2);
   /**
    * Overloaded != operator that determines whether
    * two process control blocks are different.
    * @param pcb1 a process control block
    * @param pcb2 a process control block
    * @return true if the PCBs are different; otherwise, false
    */   
   friend bool operator!=(const PCB& pcb1, const PCB& pcb2);
   /**
    * Overloaded > operator that determines whether
    * the first PCB has a higher priority than the second.
    * @param pcb1 a process control block
    * @param pcb2 a process control block
    * @return true if the first PCB has a higher priority than the second;
    * otherwise, false
    */      
   friend bool operator>(const PCB& pcb1, const PCB& pcb2);
   /**
    * Overloaded < operator that determines whether
    * the first PCB has a lower priority than the second.
    * @param pcb1 a process control block
    * @param pcb2 a process control block
    * @return true if the first PCB has a lower priority than the second;
    * otherwise, false
    */    
   friend bool operator<(const PCB& pcb1, const PCB& pcb2);
   /**
    * Overloaded >= operator that determines whether
    * the first PCB has the same or higher priority than the second.
    * @param pcb1 a process control block
    * @param pcb2 a process control block
    * @return true if the first PCB has the same or higher priority than 
    * the second; otherwise, false
    */     
   friend bool operator>=(const PCB& pcb1, const PCB& pcb2);
   /**
    * Overloaded <= operator that determines whether
    * the first PCB has the same or lower priority than the second.
    * @param pcb1 a process control block
    * @param pcb2 a process control block
    * @return true if the first PCB has the same or lower priority than 
    * the second; otherwise, false
    */    
   friend bool operator<=(const PCB& pcb1, const PCB& pcb2);
};

bool operator==(const PCB& pcb1, const PCB& pcb2)
{ 
   return (pcb1.running == pcb2.running &&
           pcb1.priority == pcb2.priority &&
           pcb1.arrived == pcb2.arrived);
}   

bool operator!=(const PCB& pcb1, const PCB& pcb2)
{   
   return (!(pcb1 == pcb2));
}   

bool operator>(const PCB& pcb1, const PCB& pcb2)
{   
   if (pcb1.running > pcb2.running)
      return true;
   if (pcb1.running < pcb2.running)
      return false;
   if (pcb1.priority < pcb2.priority)
      return true;
   if (pcb1.priority > pcb2.priority)
      return false;
   if (pcb1.arrived < pcb2.arrived)
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}   

bool operator<(const PCB& pcb1, const PCB& pcb2)
{   
   return ((pcb1 != pcb2) && !(pcb1 > pcb2));
}   

bool operator<=(const PCB& pcb1, const PCB& pcb2)
{   
   return (pcb1 > pcb2 || pcb1 == pcb2);
}   

bool operator>=(const PCB& pcb1, const PCB& pcb2)
{   
   return (pcb1 > pcb2 || pcb1 == pcb2);
}
```

And my main so far (my question appears in the if statement where I add a PCB type to the heap. Just want some sense of direction for where I should take this because I'm lost)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Heap.cpp"
#include "PCB.h"

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int j = 1;
    Heap<PCB> a;
        for (int i = 0; i < atoi(argv[2]); i++){
            double q = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
            double r = atof(argv[1]);

            cout<<"*** Cycle #: "<<i+1<<endl;

            if (q <= r){

                PCB b(j,rand() % 39 + (-20), 0, i + 1, rand() % 100 + 1); 
                a.insert(b);
                j++; 
                cout << "Adding job with pid #" <<b.getPid<<" and priority ";
                cout << b.getPriority() << " and length "<< b.getLength();
                cout << endl;
                j++;
                }
            else 
            { cout << "No new job this cycle" << endl;}

            if ()
        }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Went through your insert method. Looks like you need a minheap and you are building a maxheap !!!

Comment: In your remove method, rather than using back(), you should have used pop_back()